# How can I `put` new values in an already existing objectStore in an already existing indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, indexeddb

I am tying myself up in knots trying to update a series of four entries in an `objectStore` in an `indexedDB`.

This is what I want to achieve (in pseudo-code):

```
let myDatabase = indexedDB('myDatabase', 1);
let myObjectStore = myDatabase.myObjectStore;
myObjectStore.entry1 = 'newValue1';
myObjectStore.entry2 = 'newValue2';
myObjectStore.entry3 = 'newValue3';
myObjectStore.entry4 = 'newValue4';
```

But of course, it isn't anything like that straightforward.

I understand I need to use `put`. But,  despite numerous attempted approaches, I can't get further than that.

I *have* got as far as successfully setting up and populating the `objectStore` in the first place when the `indexedDB` is first created:

```
// SET UP VALUES OBJECT

let valuesObject = {

  entry1 : 'a',
  entry2 : 'b',
  entry3 : 'c',
  entry4 : 'd'
};


// SET UP INDEXED DATABASE

const setUpIndexedDatabase = (valuesObject) => {

  let database
  const databaseVersion = 1; 
  const databaseName = \'myDatabase\';
  const databaseOpenRequest = indexedDB.open(databaseName, databaseVersion);

  databaseOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded = () => {

    database = databaseOpenRequest.result;

    let myObjectStore = database.createObjectStore('myObjectStore');

    myObjectStore.transaction.oncomplete = () => {

      let objectStoreValues = database.transaction('Values', 'readwrite').objectStore('Values');

      const valuesEntries = Object.entries(valuesObject);

      for (let i = 0; i < valuesEntries.length; i++) {

        objectStoreValues.add(valuesEntries[i][1], valuesEntries[i][0]);
      }
    }
  }


  databaseOpenRequest.onsuccess = () => {

    database = databaseOpenRequest.result;

    // >>> THIS IS THE BIT THAT I NEED TO WRITE <<<

    database.close();
  }
}

setUpIndexedDatabase(valuesObject);
```

So far, so good. The code above fires the `onupgradeneeded` event if no database exists yet, which creates `myObjectStore` and populates it with four key-value pairs.

But if the database does exist and already contains `myObjectStore`, then every variation of code I have written using `put` fails to update the values for the keys and returns various errors - and quite often no errors at all.

All I want to do is update values in the database.

I think the problem is that I don't know how to use `put` properly when the Database Version remains unchanged and `onupgradeneeded` doesn't fire.

Comment: The code in `myObjectStore.transaction.oncomplete` is working. It's the code in `databaseOpenRequest.onsuccess` which isn't.

Comment: @Rounin, can you better explain what are you trying to achieve? When the database is created you are inserting (in the `onupgradeneeded` callback) four entries in the database. The first one has key 'a' and value 'entry1', the second has key 'b' and value 'entry2', and so on. What do you want to update in the `success` callback?

Comment: I want to access that same database later on and update the respective value for each of the four keys. So now I want `entry1` to have a value of `e`,  `entry2` to have a value of `f` etc.  I have successfully achieved this already by checking to see if the objectStore exists, deleting the objectStore, changing the version of the database and creating a new database with a new version. But I am almost certain that I should not have to create a new database simply to change some values contained within the current database.

Comment: But the values in the `valuesObject` have not changed, where are you getting the new values?

Comment: There is a new `valuesObject`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update an already existing value in the database, you can do so with the following code (as example, I am updating the `entry1` entry):

```
databaseOpenRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
    db = event.target.result;

    const objectStore = db.transaction('myObjectStore', 'readwrite').objectStore('myObjectStore');
    const request = objectStore.put('e', 'entry1');
    request.onerror = function(event) {
        // There was an error while updating.
    };
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        // The update was successful.
    };
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you _so_ much for your help with the correct syntax, @mgarcia.